# How to find a key(integer) in a string

Tags: python

How to find user entered key in a string?
This is my code so far, I'm currently a beginner in python so help and tips are greatly appreciated.

```
string = input("Please enter a name> ")


def enumerate_string(string):
    s = {}
    for i,letter in enumerate(string):
        s[i] = letter
    return s

x = enumerate_string(string)
key = input("please enter key(integer)> ")
if key in x:
    print(x.get(key))
```

The result I'm looking for is, if the user enters "z", to find the key and the value from dictionary

Comment: `if the user enters "z"`? You are asking for an integer. It might help make the question clearer if you show what you expect given both inputs.

Comment: Yes, please show expected input and output. Also explain why the current code isn't doing what you want (`input("please enter key(integer)> ")` returns you a string, not an integer). How do you convert that to an integer? How do you handle the exceptions if isn't a number, or isn't a legal integer, in range?

Comment: Also, your function `enumerate_string()` is unnecessary, it can be replaced with simply `dict(enumerate(s))`

Comment: example if the user entered csc the display is {0:'c' , 1:'s', 2:'c'} which the first part of the code is correct, but if the user tries to find the integer associated with key the display should be {0:'c'}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what your trying to get at:

enumerate_string will take a string and return a dictionary of letter,index key value pairs. The problem with your original code was you didnt specify that the "key" should be of type "int". I cast the int type below:

Hope this helps!

```js
def enumerate_string(string):
    s = {} 
    for i,letter in enumerate(string):
        s[i] = letter 
    return s

string = input("Please enter a name ")

x = enumerate_string("string") 
key = int(input("please enter key(integer):") )
if key in x: 
    print(x[key])
```

Comment: You might like to catch the exception if `key` is not an integer (whitespace, letter, punctuation, mixed etc.) i.e. don't just assume `int(input(...))` works.

Comment: That work perfectly, Thank you so much Maxfield Green

Comment: @ZekeMedina glad to here it! want to accept the answer in case others run into the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
key = input("please enter key(integer)> ")
```

key is a string, so convert it into an integer before checking if it's a key:

```
key_int = int(key.strip())
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for your input. decided to modify my code a little. let me know what you think?

```
x = enumerate_string(string)
key = input("please enter key(integer):")
try:
   val = int(key)
   if key in x:
      print("The value of key is: ",x[key])
   else:
      print("Error key not found. ")
except ValueError:
   print("that is not an integer")
   print("please enter an Integer")
```